# Modulus of large numbers

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I am learning for an exam and want to understand this:

Calculate $3^{142} \mod 50$.

Solution:

$\operatorname{HCF}(3, 50) = 1$

$\varphi(50) = \varphi(5 \cdot 5 \cdot 2) = \varphi(5^2 \cdot 2) = \varphi(5^2) \cdot \varphi(2) = 20 \implies$

$3^{20}\equiv 1 \mod 50$    // <- **oO**

$3^{142} = 3^{140+2} = 3^{7\cdot 20} \cdot 9 \equiv 9 \mod 50.$

I solved it for myself and I struggle when the solution says $3^{20} \equiv 1 \mod 50$. Please help me to understand this step.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler's_theorem